# How can I obtain a list of labels using Google Drive's API?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-workspace, google-api-python-client

I'm attempting to perform tag searching in my Google Drive. Specifically, I need to query the list of every file I have along with their associated tags.  I have followed the instructions outlined here https://developers.google.com/drive/labels/quickstart/python to the letter. I have downloaded the OAuth .json file from the credentials page in my Google Cloud Console. I have renamed the .json file to token.json. When I run quickstart.py, I get the following error. I have an inkling that the casue is due to the OAuth handshake is not done properly in the sample code.

```
 (googleworkspace) C:\projects\Google Workspace 
IntelliSearch\PyDrive2-CLI\pydrive2_cli\testbranch\Jupyter>python 
quickstart.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\projects\Google Workspace 
IntelliSearch\PyDrive2-CLI\pydrive2_cli\testbranch\Jupyter\quickstart.py", 
line 52, in <module>
main()
File "C:\projects\Google Workspace 
IntelliSearch\PyDrive2-CLI\pydrive2_cli\testbranch\Jupyter\quickstart.py", 
line 22, in main
creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File 
"C:\Users\Dom\.conda\envs\googleworkspace\Lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\credentials.py", 
line 440, in from_authorized_user_file
return cls.from_authorized_user_info(data, scopes)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File 
"C:\Users\Dom\.conda\envs\googleworkspace\Lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\credentials.py", 
line 390, in from_authorized_user_info
raise ValueError(
ValueError: Authorized user info was not in the expected format, missing 
fields refresh_token, client_secret, client_id.
```

Editors Note: SPAM Detection triggered, majority of code, json file and directory tree omitted.

I have tested with Desktop and Web Oauth json files, both fails. I have tested with API service worker json files, that fails too.
I have tested on Windows and Ubuntu, all platform fails.
I have used the following links:

Editors note: LINKS OMITTED, insufficent reputation

The only thing that works is the test API pages on here.
https://developers.google.com/drive/labels/reference/rest/v2/labels/list
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/drives/list
As well as the test API page on here.

GO TO
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
ENTER
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.labels
CHOOSE
google account
CLICK
"Allow"
CLICK
"Authorise API"
CLICK
"Exchange authorization code for tokens"
ENTER
HTTP Method: GET
Request URL: https://drivelabels.googleapis.com/v2/labels

I have ran the commands to pip upgrade all the libraries as per https://developers.google.com/drive/labels/quickstart/python . Anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?